# Querying Firebase with Angular to get document keys

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a data structure like this in Firebase. It holds the times that people were basically logged in and on what screen (their sessions on an app)

```
session
-- bob
--- sessions
---- 0BDRMuw95DFXhWRH7n0s
----- { 15:00, 16:00}
---- ABDRMuw95DFXhWRH7n0s
----- { 16:00, 16:30}
-- jess
--- sessions
---- 0BDRMuw95DFXhWRH7n0s
----- { 10:00, 11:00}
---- LBDRMuw95DFXhWRH7n0s
----- { 16:00, 16:30}
```

​
So, for example to get a user "bob's" dession of a particular id, I would need to query:
​
`session/bob/sessions/0BDRMuw95DFXhWRH7n0s`

And get back the session of { 15:00, 16:00}
​
If I would like to get a list of sessions to a particular user,  I would do this

```
this.items$ = db.collection<any>('session/bob/sessions').valueChanges();
this.items$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Then I get a list of all his sessions.

Now my confusion is this. The above code works perfectly well to get a list of session for bob.
​
However, what I want to get is a list of users! Which I thought would be like this:
`this.items$ = db.collection<any>('session').valueChanges();`

I thought this would return 'bob' and 'jess'​

So that I could get a list of all of the users who have a 'session' and then query each user accordingly to get all their sessions, kind of like this:
`this.items$ = db.collection<any>('session/' + user_id + '/sessions').valueChanges();`
​

However this `this.items$ = db.collection<any>('session').valueChanges();` 
always returns an empty array.
​
I've also tried `snapshotChanges()` instead of `valueChanges()`, and this also returns an empty array!
​
Is there an error in my thinking in terms of how this works?

I'm using the AngularFirestore: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2
​

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#valuechanges), `valueChanges()` doesn't include the `id` (All metadata is stripped)

> **valueChanges()**
>   What is it? - The current state of your collection. Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of JSON objects. All Snapshot metadata is stripped and just the method provides only the data.

In your case, `bob` and `jess` are id's. So if you want only want to have the `ìd's` you need to use `snapshotChanges()`

> I've also tried snapshotChanges() instead of valueChanges(), and this also returns an empty array! ​

Well, since your code with `snapshotChanges()` isn't included in the post, it's hard to guess what went wrong, but it should be used like this:

```
this.db.collection('session').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(actions => actions.map(a => a.payload.doc.id)));
```